# problema do evento blur com botão submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário-submeter, onblur

Boa tarde, tenho um form, nele tem um campo text que dispara o evento .blur que pega o nome digitado e retorna um id com ajax, pega o id salva em outro input hidden, o problema é que o evento blur só é disparado se clicar em lugar vazio (para perder o foco) e depois no botão submit, se clicar diretamente no submit não é disparado o evento blur, alguma solução para tal problema? já tentei mudar para evento change mas também não funcionou se clicar diretamente no submit.

```
 $("#responsavel").blur(function(){var cdgResp  = $("#responsavel").val();$.post("controller/responsavel.php",  {nomeResponsavel:cdgResp} , function(idResp) {if (idResp != false){$("#idResponsavel").val(idResp); }else { $("#idResponsavel").val("0"); } });});
```

acima está o javascript que dispara o blur

```
<form action="javascript:func()" method="post">action="javascript:func()" method="post"><input id="responsavel" type="text" name="responsavel" value=<?php echo $dados['responsavel']; ?>"><input id="idResponsavel" type="hidden" name="idResponsavel" value="<?php echo $dados['idResponsavel']; ?>"><input type="submit" value="enviar"></form>
```

e acima esta o form, criei agora de forma genérica pra exemplificar melhor, os dados ja vem preenchido com php mas caso mude o nome do campo responsável teria que mudar o id do mesmo.

Comment: Tem que por o código amigo para receber ajuda adequada!

Comment: Bom dia, alterei a descrição exemplificando o meu problema.

Comment: Tentou o "onfocusout" ? Tenta dar uma olhada na lista de enventos do js: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: Na verdade o evento blur até está sendo disparado, mas como é um AJAX que faz ali o submit do form está acontecendo antes do AJAX terminar de ser processado, logo não da tempo de preencher o campo hidden. Tem que sempre lembrar que AJAX são requisições em paralelo. Para o seu caso eu recomendo usar $.ajax ao invés de $.post e usar o atributo ```async: false```

Comment: Já tentei sim @andreia_sp , mas não deu certo.

Comment: @LucasFerreira é exatamente isso que esta acontecendo, está disparando mas os dados que vão para o submit não é alterado, obrigado pela dica, vou tentar dessa forma com async:false

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o:

> keyup

(clique em executar para ver um exemplo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keydown(function(){
        $("input").css("background-color", "yellow");
        
    });
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $("input").css("background-color", "pink");
        $("#resposta").append("<br>Requisitando...");
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#resposta").empty(); }, 500);
        
        //aqui ficará seu ajax...Sempre buscando por um id...
        //Utilize um loading, para travar o botao submit, 
        //até a requisição terminar, dura menos de um segundo
         
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Nome digitado: <input type="text">
<div id="resposta"></div>
<br><br><br>
<p>Digite uma letra. Toda vez que ele ficar YELLOW e voltar para o PINK, um evento irá verificar e retornar o ID.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Lollipop, em um caso comum funcionaria, mas no meu caso não deu certo por que nesse mesmo campo text eu uso o autocomplete do jquery, então quando inicio a digitação aparece uma lista de nomes eu seleciono (tipo um select), dai nesse caso já não é disparado o keyup, ao menos que continuasse digitando o nome até o fim

Comment: Mas você não falou que utilizava o autocomplet...E o autocomplet tem seus events, não é pra você ficar usando o input pra isso.

Comment: Não entendi sua colocação sobre "não usar input para isso" mas fui pesquisa sobre os eventos do autocomplet (que não sabia que tinha) e achei o "select" e o "change"  talvez isso resolva meu problema, obrigado!

Comment: esse exemplo aqui resolve meu problema http://www.tutorialspark.com/jqueryUI/jQuery_UI_AutoComplete_Overridding_Default_Select_Action.php

Comment: Exatamente, meu querido. Quando for usar qualquer plugin e precisar implementar algo, veja se a documentação tem o que voce precisa.